# Extract specific value using Beautifulsoap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was scraping this website (https://www.ivolatility.com/options/RVX/) using python module request. The output from the selection of the first table using beautifulsoap is above. Now, inside of this first table I am trying to get a specific value (19.17) from this soup obtained from python module requests.

I would like to achieve it using Beautifulsoap, I don't know how to specifically select the cell where it is saved.

Do any of you have any suggestions?

Output from requests:

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="red" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><script language="JavaScript">



function submitCalcForm(event) {
event.preventDefault();

            var form = document.getElementById('basicOptionsForm');
var action = form.action;
var regions = ['', 'USA', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Canada'];
var regionsOptions = form[1];
var selectedRegion = regionsOptions.options[regionsOptions.selectedIndex].value;
var symbol = form[0].value.trim();
var location = (window.location.href.indexOf('.j')>-1) 
    ? (form.action + '?' + form[0].name + '=' + form[0].value + '&' + form[1].name + '=' + selectedRegion)
    : ('/options/'+ ((symbol == '') ? '-' : symbol ) +'/'+regions[selectedRegion]); 

            window.location.href= location;

}


function goToLookup() {
    window.location.href= "/options/-/";
}


</script>
<form action="/options.j" id="basicOptionsForm" method="get" onsubmit="submitCalcForm(event);">
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table bgcolor="#999999" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#567abb">
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="table-action">
<tr>
<td><span class="s1w" style="color: #fff;"> Symbol: </span></td><td><input class="s2" name="ticker" size="5" type="text" value="RVX"/></td><td><select class="s2" name="R"><option selected="" value="0">
                ALL
            </option><option value="1">
                USA
            </option><option value="2">
                Europe
            </option><option value="4">
                Canada
            </option></select></td><td><span class="s2"> </span></td><td><button style="background: #0C6EF8;    font-weight: bold;    border: 1px solid black;" type="submit">GO!</button></td><td><span class="s2"> </span></td><td><button onclick="goToLookup();" style="background: #0C6EF8;    font-weight: bold;    border: 1px solid black; color: white; white-space: nowrap;" type="button">
                                                        Symbol Lookup</button></td><td><span class="s2"> </span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td><td><img border="0" height="1" src="/design/images/0.gif" width="5"/></td><td nowrap=""><b><span class="s4">Russell 2000 Volatility Index</span></b></td><td width="100%"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><img alt="." border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/0.gif" width="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td width="100%"><script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    function wr(s) {
      document.write(s);
    }
    var d = new Array(10);
    d[20]='N/A';d[25]='-94.06%';d[30]='32.03%';d[35]='34.74';d[56]='N/A';d[61]='N/A';d[66]='10-Apr';d[71]='84.49%';d[97]='N/A';d[102]='03-Oct';d[107]='29-Mar';d[112]='1.43';d[133]='N/A';d[138]='N/A';d[143]='148.97%';d[148]='98.46%';d[174]='N/A';d[179]='-46.88%';d[184]='198.21%';d[189]='0.27';d[210]='N/A';d[215]='N/A';d[220]='25-May';d[225]='110.30%';d[251]='N/A';d[256]='-68.76%';d[261]='75.38%';d[266]='0';d[287]='N/A';d[292]='N/A';d[297]='39.85%';d[302]='120.02%';d[328]='N/A';d[333]='-67.09%';d[338]='69.94%';d[343]='19.17';d[364]='N/A';d[369]='N/A';d[374]='06-Apr';d[379]='06/14/2018';d[405]='N/A';d[410]='-82.49%';d[415]='74.41%';d[441]='N/A';d[446]='N/A';d[451]='164.16%';d[456]='12.93';d[482]='N/A';d[487]='24-May';d[492]='77.70%';d[518]='N/A';d[523]='03-May';d[528]='21-May';d[533]='12/24/2018';d[559]='N/A';d[564]='59.42%';d[569]='84.78%';

    wr('<table class="table-data" cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border=0 width=100%>');
    wr('<tr bgcolor="#cccccc" align=right height=20>');
    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1>Price</font></td>');
    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1>Change&nbsp;(%)</font><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width=4 height=1 border=0/></td>');
    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1>52&nbsp;wk&nbsp;High</font><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width=4 height=1 border=0/></td>');
    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1>52&nbsp;wk&nbsp;Low</font><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width=4 height=1 border=0/></td>');


    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1>Stock volume</font>');



    wr('<a href="javascript:openHelp(14)" alt="Open Help">');
    wr('<img src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width=8 height=10 border=0 alt="Open Help"/>');
    wr('</a><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width=4 height=1 border=0/></td>');



    wr('</tr>');
    wr('<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align=right height=20>');
    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1>');
    wr(d[343]);
    wr('</font></td>');
    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1><nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;');


      wr('<img src="/design/images/ico/up.gif" alt="+" border=0 align="absmiddle" width=7 height=9/>&nbsp;+');



    wr(d[189]);
    wr('&nbsp;(+');
    wr(d[112]);
    wr('%)</nobr></font></td>');
    wr('<td align="center"><font class=s1><nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    wr(d[35]);
    wr('&nbsp;');
    wr(d[533]);
    wr('</nobr></font></td><td align="center"><font class=s1><nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    wr(d[456]);
    wr('&nbsp;');
    wr(d[379]);
    wr('</nobr></font></td>');


    wr('<td align="center"><font size=-2 class=s1>');
    wr(d[266]);
    wr('</font></td>');



    wr('</tr></table>');
  //--> 

  </script><img border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/0.gif" width="1"/><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table-data" width="100%">
<tr align="center" bgcolor="
        #cccccc
    " height="20">
<td align="center" colspan="2"><font class="s2">Current</font></td><td><font class="s2">1 WK AGO</font></td><td><font class="s2">1 MO AGO</font></td><td><font class="s2">52 wk Hi/Date</font></td><td><font class="s2">52 wk Low/Date</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="
        #FFFFFF
    " colspan="5" height="20"><font class="s2" color="">  HISTORICAL VOLATILITY <a alt="Open Help" href="javascript:openHelp(4)"><img alt="Open Help" border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8"/></a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td align="right"><font class="s2">10 days</font></td><td><font class="s2">120.02%</font></td><td><font class="s2">84.49%</font></td><td><font class="s2">74.41%</font></td><td><font class="s2">198.21% - 29-Mar</font></td><td><font class="s2">32.03% - 21-May</font></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<td align="right"><font class="s2">20 days</font></td><td><font class="s2">110.30%</font></td><td><font class="s2">84.78%</font></td><td><font class="s2">69.94%</font></td><td><font class="s2">164.16% - 06-Apr</font></td><td><font class="s2">39.85% - 25-May</font></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td align="right"><font class="s2">30 days</font></td><td><font class="s2">98.46%</font></td><td><font class="s2">77.70%</font></td><td><font class="s2">75.38%</font></td><td><font class="s2">148.97% - 10-Apr</font></td><td><font class="s2">59.42% - 24-May</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="
        #FFFFFF
    " colspan="5" height="20"><font class="s2" color="">  IMPLIED VOLATILITY <a href="javascript:openHelp(12)"><img alt="Open Help" border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8"/></a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td align="right"><font class="s2">IV Index call <a href="javascript:openHelp(9)"><img alt="Open Help" border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8"/></a></font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A - N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A - N/A</font></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<td align="right"><font class="s2">IV Index put <a href="javascript:openHelp(10)"><img alt="Open Help" border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8"/></a></font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A - N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A - N/A</font></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td align="right"><font class="s2">IV Index mean <a href="javascript:openHelp('ivxmean')"><img alt="Open Help" border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8"/></a></font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A - N/A</font></td><td><font class="s2">N/A - N/A</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="
        #FFFFFF
    " colspan="5" height="20"><font class="s2" color="">HISTORICAL 30-DAYS CORRELATION AGAINST S&amp;P 500 Index (SPX)<a href="javascript:openHelp(30)"><img alt="Open Help" border="0" height="10" src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8"/></a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td align="right"><font class="s2">30 days</font></td><td><font class="s2">-82.49%</font></td><td><font class="s2">-67.09%</font></td><td><font class="s2">-68.76%</font></td><td><font class="s2">-46.88% - 03-Oct</font></td><td><font class="s2">-94.06% - 03-May</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: since the value `19.17` in column `price` is rendered with `JavaScript`, you can't scrap this element using `BeautifulSoup`. What you need is then `Selenium`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is dynamic so you'd need to render the page first with something like Selenium.

Also, you can use BeautfifulSoup, or even Selenium, to parse the html once you have it. But I noticed that it's located within `<table>` tags. Whenever I see a `<table>` tag, I usually opt to go with pandas' `.read_html()` as it'll do the hard work for you.

`.read_html()` will return a list of dataframes, then it's just a matter of finding the data you want, or maniupulate the table as needed. The data you want was found in the dataframe in index position `4`, (it was also in position `0`, but I choose to go with `4` since it was right there, 2nd row, first column). Then just slice that dataframe to get hat specific cell:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.ivolatility.com/options/RVX/'
driver.get(url) 

tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

price = tables[4][0][1]

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (price)
19.17
```